# How to read the data of the last 3 days from a folder with parquet files?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, parquet

I have a folder with many parquet files that have names as follows:

```
user_2018-03-15_checked_products.parquet
user_2018-03-15_unchecked_products.parquet
user_2018-03-14_checked_products.parquet
user_2018-03-14_unchecked_products.parquet
user_2018-03-13_checked_products.parquet
user_2018-03-13_unchecked_products.parquet
user_2018-03-12_checked_products.parquet
user_2018-03-12_unchecked_products.parquet
```

I read all files as follows:

```
val df = spark.read.parquet("path/to/folder")
```

The folder contains 100 Gb of data and its size is growing incrementally. But I need to read only the data for the last 3 days. Currently, I read the whole folder and then apply `filter`? Is it possible to use some kind of mask in order to select only those file names that belong to the last 3 days instead of reading the whole folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read all the file names and `filter` the file that is within 3 days as.

```
val listOfFiles = ??? // read all the files names 

val filteredFile = listOfFiles.filter( file => {
  val dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")
  val fileDate =  dateFormat.parse(file.split("_")(1))  //get date from file name 
  val currentDate = dateFormat.parse(dateFormat.format(new Date())) // current date
  val days = Days.daysBetween(new LocalDateTime(fileDate), new LocalDateTime(currentDate)).getDays
  //difference in days

  if (days <= 3 && days >= 0) true else false
})
```

Now read the list of filtered files as

```
spark.read.parquet(filteredFile: _*)
```

If require append the paths.

Hope this helps!

Comment: How can I read all the file names ? `val listOfFiles = ??? // read all the files names`

Comment: Is it in local or HDFS ?

Comment: It's in S3 (Amazon). Currently I do not fully get the point of your answer.

Comment: There should be a Java SDK or API to get all the file names from s3 directory. Get the list of all file names and use above filter. And read the list of files.

Comment: What do you mean by `If require append the paths.`? Do you mean that I should append `.parquet`?

Comment: You get the list of files, but you don't have a full path so you need to append the pre-path to the files name.

Comment: I assume that if I use AmazonS3, I get full paths in listOfFiles, e.g. mybucket/myfolder/user_2018-03-12_checked_products.parquet

Comment: Ok that should be fine than, But your path should not contaion `_` otherwise it breaks the split.